# android - how can I get time in sleep

Tags: android

Does anyone know of a way to get the time the device has been in sleep?  I am trying to get Awake Time for the device battery and I can get the total time since boot using SystemClock, but they do not have a method for sleepTime.  If I could get sleep time, I could do totalTime - sleepTime and get the awakeTime, but not sure on how to get sleep time.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: If you need a total elapsed time, why not just get the current time?

Comment: @Telthien im not sure how using the current time can help me get the awake time..im trying to ultimately get the time the system has been awake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` is "the time since the system was booted, and include deep sleep".

`SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` is "counted in milliseconds since the system was booted. This clock stops when the system enters deep sleep (CPU off, display dark, device waiting for external input), but is not affected by clock scaling, idle, or other power saving mechanisms."

Hence, `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()-SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` should be the amount of time in "deep sleep".